# How to streamline setting up a multi-day class

Tags: civievent

I'm using CiviCRM for, amongst other things, recording registration and attendance for short (1-2 week) adult education classes. I would like to be able to register each learner for the class and then be able to record their attendance on each day.

I can set up repeating events for each day, but whether I set the repeat up first then register the participant, or the other way round, the participant is only registered on the specific event chosen and not the others in the repeating set. If I make one event span the multiple days, I only get one attendance status for the whole thing.

I can just register them for each day, but that's extra work for our staff and adds potential for mistakes, so I'd rather not do that if there's a better way.

The registrations will be done only by our staff, there's no 'self service' online registrations.

CiviCRM 4.7.15 on Drupal 7.53.

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to create a custom field for participants with check boxes for each day. Then you could record attendance without having multiple events. You could use the Batch Update via Profile feature to make recording attendance easier for you staff.

Not sure how many events or exact setup. If you use a generic field labels (Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, etc.) you could re-use the custom field and not have to create ones for each event.

Hope this helps.